# Web Notification

Tags: aplicação-web, google-chrome

Bom, pesquisei por dias na web e não encontrei um tutorial completo ou vídeo aula de como fazer isso :/ espero que vocês aqui da stackoverflow me ajudem kkkk.

Bom eu preciso criar um desses sistemas de notificação igual o facebook, gmail, workana entre outros sites fazem, um exemplo: quando alguem te marca no facebook aparece uma notificação na tela.

eu já tentei de tudo aqui kkk mas parece que meu nível sobre o assunto não me ajudou a conseguir o sucesso :/

tentei com o firebase - Socket.IO enfim oq eu achei pela frente fui tentando mas sem sucesso algum...

alguém, aqui sabe como fazer isso, e tem um tutorial do tipo: segue isso que funciona lkkk

obrigado!!!

Comment: Também queria saber.... Que respostas demoradas....